# ORM Like Framework for Semantic Data?

Tags: dao, semantic-web, object-object-mapping

Is there an graph to object mapping framework for handling RDF? I would like to get some recommendations and any personal experiences.

**Background Details:**

I have an application that has been using Oracle, because of the dynamic nature of the data, we have decided to replace the oracle db with an semantic data store. I have written module to perform sparql queries and return Jena Objects.  I would like to minimize the changes to other layers, so I was wondering if there is an framework in place, that I can substitute, for my existing Hibernate ORM layer. ( Present Architecture Oracle DB -> JPA (backed by hibernate) -> Session Beans (exposed as WS).